# Formatting an integer

Tags: vb6, vbscript

I have almost a two part question.  Firstly, I am trying to format a string that I have converted to an integer. I have the following code:

```
If Idx2 = 0 Then    
    response.Write(sName & vbKeyTab & " E01 " & vbKeyTab & CInt(oSplit(1)) & "</br>")
End If
```

This correctly displays my value in `oSplit(1)` as `75`. I'd like to to display as `00075.00`

I've tried this, but I get a 500 error:

```
Format(CInt(oSplit(1)), "00000.00")
```

My second question is regarding the `CInt` portion of my code. The data in my `oSplit` array is a string, and I am casting it to an integer. However, it seems as if `CInt` is rounding my values. Is there a parameter I can pass to `CInt` to prevent this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say you want to prevent rounding- do you mean that you want to prevent rounding UP? i.e. 64.6 should give 00064.00.

Comment: @BonyT Correct. I would like `.05` to be shown as `00000.05` not `00001.00`.

Comment: err - that's not what I put - if you want .05 to show as 00000.05 then you are dealing with decimals not integers

Comment: Is there a function to cast my string to a decimal?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be VB6 at all, but *VBScript* in classic ASP.  vbKeyTab is a numeric keycode constant and you probably want vbTab which is a Tab character.  There is no "casting" going on here at all, but instead you are doing *conversions* which are an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle .05 then you want to convert it to a decimal not an Int:

```
  Format(CDec(oSplit(1)), "00000.00")
```

Comment: While conversion to Decimal will work it implies things that are not in play here and has more overhead than Single or Double.  Use CSng() here instead.

Comment: or just `Val()` for a variant (and implicit 0 conversion)